# Scapy and sniff. how can I filter TCP SYN?

Tags: python, scapy

```
pkts=sniff(offline="/home/jaghanata/Desktop/amostra.pcap", filter='tcp')
```

how can I filter TCP SYN ?

Comment: pkts=sniff(offline="/home/jaghanata/Desktop/amostra.pcap", filter='tcp-syn') dont do nothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scapy` filters are full [Berkeley Packet Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter), therefore you can do:

```
pkts = sniff(offline="amostra.pcap", filter='tcp and tcp.flags.syn==1')
```

Or, more likely, you want this:

```
myfilter = 'tcp and tcp.flags.syn==1 and tcp.flags.ack==0'
pkts = sniff(offline="amostra.pcap", filter=myfilter)
```

Since what is often called a *SYN packet* are the ones that go first from the connecting party.  The returning packets have the SYN flag set as well but they are called *SYN/ACK packets* and have both SYN and ACK flags set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!